# Securimage CAPTCHA does not protect

Tags: php, captcha

I have installed the [Securimage CAPTCHA](http://www.phpcaptcha.org) on my forms. However after installation, I see that it is not protecting me from spam: all spam messages are coming through. I tried manually and it works as expected.

I guess bots are recognizing the captcha images. How can I make it more reliable? Before this I was using hn_captcha and it was protecting, but I did not like the way it works (storing images in cache). But I guess php captcha is more popular.

Comment: I believe the problem is in your code, I'm very sure of it ..

Comment: that is what I thought at first step. But I tested form, it does not accept wrong values. Here is one example, if you are interested.

http://www.yoncaayas.com/main.php?module=deytawebsite&page=pgguestbook&lang=tr

Answer (score 2):

Why not record the answer to the CAPTCHA image, and take a copy of the image, for a few hours? You can then see if messages you regard as spam have correct CAPTCHA answers.

I would also record the user agent string for each, to see whether this looks like a proper browser, or is obviously a bot. Bear in mind that it can be faked, but it should be interesting nevertheless. It's worth bearing in mind that sometimes the economics of spam are such that it is worth paying developing-country human teams to paste spam into blogs/forums, and these are a bit harder to defeat. Perhaps something like Akismet would help?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was just curious if there are some quick tweaks that I can apply to increase security. I will record information about spammers and hopefully find the source and the method.

Comment: There might be some tweaks, but you need to find out what the problem is first. Are you blacklisting IPs that make many wrong attempts? You may find if you record live data that there are 1000 visits for every successful post, which might indicate a OCR/brute-force combination.